# Convert element in std::tuple

Tags: c++, tuples

I have a `std::tuple` with strings in it and I want to convert an element of that tuple to an Integer. Is that possible?

E.g:

```
std::tuple<std::string,std::string>("1","2") --> std::tuple<int,std::string>(1,"2")
```

Comment: Write some code.

Comment: Why should this be a different problem than converting a single `std::string` to an `int`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change one of the underlying types of the [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) container during runtime then **no**, it is not possible. If you simply want to convert one of the values to `int` then you should define another tuple and utilize the [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function:

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string> t1("1", "2");
std::tuple<int, std::string> t2(std::stoi(std::get<0>(t1)), std::get<1>(t1));
```

or use the [std::make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) function and the `auto` specifier and let the compiler deduce the types:

```
auto t3 = std::make_tuple(std::stoi(std::get<0>(t1)), std::get<1>(t1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution:

```
template <std::size_t At, class NewType, class Tuple, std::size_t... Idx>
auto convertAt_impl(Tuple const &orig, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    return std::tuple{
        [&] {
            if constexpr(Idx == At)
                return boost::lexical_cast<NewType>(std::get<Idx>(orig));
            else
                return std::get<Idx>(orig);
        }()...
    };
}

template <std::size_t At, class NewType, class... Ts>
auto convertAt(std::tuple<Ts...> const &orig) {
    return convertAt_impl<At, NewType>(orig, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}
```

It makes use of `boost::lexical_cast` to perform the conversion, but you can replace it with whatever conversion facility you want.

It can be invoked like so:

```
int main() {
    std::tuple tup{"1", "2"};

    auto tup2 = convertAt<0, int>(tup);

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(tup2), std::tuple<int, char const *>>);

    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup2) << ' ' << std::get<1>(tup2) << '\n';
}
```

... which will pass the assert and print what we expect.

I would include a link to a Coliru demo, but its GCC catches fire upon pack-expanding a lambda, while its Clang has no idea of what `if constexpr` or class template argument deduction are. Heh.